# How to proxy requests to a Docker container running on the same host using Apache virtual host configuration?

Tags: docker, apache, nginx, web-applications, reverse-proxy

I have an EC2 instance running multiple Docker containers named rabbitmq, frontend, and backend. All these containers are running on a custom bridge network and they are able to communicate with each other. The frontend is running on an Apache web server, and that container's ports are mapped to the host machine's ports 80 and 443. The Apache server configuration for the virtual host is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myapp.com
   ServerAlias localhost
   Redirect permanent / https://myapp.com/app/ ---> Note this app suffix
</VirtualHost>

SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/local/apache2/conf/passphrase.sh

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName myapp.com
ServerAlias localhost

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /rest http://backend:8080/rest
ProxyPassReverse /rest http://backend:8080/rest

SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/server-bundle.crt
#SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ca.crt
#SSLCACertificatePath /usr/local/apache2/conf

</VirtualHost>
```

When users type myapp.com in a browser, the connection goes to the Apache server, which proxies requests to the backend docker container based on the path, if the path contains /rest, and so on.

I also have a RabbitMQ Docker container, called rabbitmq running on the same host, which has a management console open on port 15672. the port is already mapped to host port 15672. I want to proxy requests coming to myapp.com/rabbitmq to this container's port. I have tried several solutions, but none have helped me. Is it possible to use the same Apache server to proxy requests coming to that specific path to rabbitmq port 15672?

The reason is that as of now, I am directly accessing the management port by opening the incoming ports in AWS security rules, so the traffic is HTTP. If I remove the direct access and do some kind of proxy through a server that already handles SSL verification, I can access the same via HTTPS itself.

I have been able to solve this issue with the help of Nginx. What I did was:

- Map the frontend on a different port instead of host ports 80 and 443 of the host.
- Configure Nginx to intercept HTTP (80) / HTTPS (443) requests and proxy them to the appropriate destination (rabbitmq or frontend).
- Now Nginx will do the ssl verification, apache server doesn't have any role in that now.

By implementing these steps, the issue with proxying requests to rabbitmq can be resolved, and the frontend can run smoothly on the Apache web server. Both are accessible over HTTPS. However, my concern is whether we really need another reverse proxy server since I am already using an Apache web server in the frontend container to serve the web pages?

I have tried to modify the virtualhost entry for ssl as follows

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName myapp.com
ServerAlias localhost

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /rest http://backend:8080/rest
ProxyPassReverse /rest http://backend:8080/rest

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/rabbitmq/app(.*)$ /rabbitmq/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/rabbitmq$ /rabbitmq/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/rabbitmq/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
# Proxy requests to RabbitMQ management interface
ProxyPass /rabbitmq http://rabbitmq:15672/
ProxyPassReverse /rabbitmq http://rabbitmq:15672/

SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/server-bundle.crt
#SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ca.crt
#SSLCACertificatePath /usr/local/apache2/conf

</VirtualHost>
```

But this didnt help me. The app is working as I accepted. Byt when I access http://myapp/rabbitmq. the request goes to https://myapp/rabbitmq/ and I am getting forbidden error. Somehow the apache web server running inside frontend docker container is not able to proxy the reuest to the rabbitmq container. Does anyone have any idea on this.?